# Would a Gas Giant be a feasible option for in-atmosphere fighting?

Tags: science-based, warfare, gas-giants

Could it be possible that a large portion (80%+) of a gas giant has thin enough atmosphere that the ships don’t suffer from re-entry effects, but thick enough that conventional dogfighting tactics would work?

Bonus: if possible could jet engines be used in said atmosphere?

Comment: Re-entry effects, dogfighting and jet engines would seem to be multiple questions.

Comment: @JBH, all I’m asking is if it is possible for an atmosphere to be thick enough that powered flight is supported, but thin enough that adverse re entry trauma is avoided. The jet engines are strictly bonus

Comment: Not even *close* bud. [Van Allen radiation belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Allen_radiation_belt) "The action of the [Magnetosphere of Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere_of_Jupiter) traps and accelerates particles, producing intense belts of radiation similar to Earth's Van Allen belts, but **thousands of times stronger**."

Comment: If you're asking if it works in KSP, the answer is yes. But that the ships don’t suffer from re-entry effects is like, your job and stuff. It's a question of if you're willing to leave discarded heat shields all over the place or if it's SSTOs only. If your engine has an ISP of 2k in a vacuum and +20k while air breathing... then you can do w/e you want, where ever you want **provided there's oxidizer in the atmosphere and fuel in your tanks**.

Comment: Then there's the gravitational effects...

Comment: Great edit, very clear. +1 and Thanks! Note that the reentry issue isn't as critical as you think. There is a velocity that will burn up in any atmosphere regardless how thin it is. Conversely, you can always slow down enough to get through any atmosphere without burning up regardless how thick it is. Therefore, reentry is solved via a story-based solution (your dogfighters slow down to enter the atmosphere). What you won't have is a high-speed chase into an atmosphere that meets both criteria. Burn, baby, burn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**

In order to be able to have a "conventional dogfight", the atmosphere must be thick enough that the control surfaces of the hypothetical fighter aerospace craft are able to interact with it.  (Otherwise the fighter is in vacuum and can only change its vector by expending reaction mass, which is what you are presumably trying to avoid.)

The problem is, that as soon as there is enough atmosphere that it is possible to change direction by interacting with it using airfoils, there is more than enough atmosphere that re-entry will have occurred.  If you look at [Earth's atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_atmospheric_model#The_U.S._Standard_Atmosphere), by the time you have even 10% of the air density at sea level (meaning that, to a rough approximation, all maneuvers will require ten times more distance to complete than they would at sea level) you are well below an altitude of 20 km and have definitely undergone atmospheric re-entry.

To try to give an intuitive feel for this, imagine that a Q-wing space fighter above Uranus is being pursued by a R-wing fighter.  (Hopefully neither of these letters have been trademarked by a certain space fantasy franchise.)  The Q-wing wants to dive into the atmosphere so it can pull an [Immelman turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immelmann_turn), make a quick firing pass and fly in the opposite direction to escape, without expending vast amounts of reaction mass.  The problem is that the escape velocity of Uranus is 21.3 km/s, almost twice that of Earth.  Assuming that the pilot and fighter can withstand a sustained 10G maneuver and survive the re-entry (handwaved), it will take over half an hour to shed its "forward" momentum before it can start flying in the opposite direction - undoubtedly the longest Immelmann turn in history.

If you really want to have atmospheric dogfighting then you are better off with a very small planet with (somehow) a comparatively dense atmosphere.  This reduces the re-entry velocity - which is basically the escape velocity - to a much more manageable number.  However, there is still no way to avoid re-entry.

My personal suggestion would be to embrace the zero-G, no atmosphere conditions and use the type of maneuvers that the Star Furies in [Babylon 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5) used - take advantage of the absence of an atmosphere to pull stunts that are not possible in one.  (I think it was the start of the season 2 final The Fall of Night where they are training in some of these.)  Of course, both sides have to cooperate to have a low-relative-speed dogfight, it is generally more realistic to have a single high-speed firing pass followed by hours of changing vector before the next pass.

Comment: Maybe you could do it without reentry trauma in a gas giant. Saturn's scale height is 60 km. Compare to Earth's 8.5 km.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw the scale height is greater, but the distance required to decelerate down to atmospheric flying speeds scales with the square of the escape velocity.  Happy to be proven wrong if it's possible, though.

Comment: I think you're right. I have thought about this and I can't figure a realistic way for ships to decelerate for a dog fight without either a classic reentry or some very anticlimatic, weirdly slow descent phase.

Comment: At this point, it might be faster to use the gravity well of the gas giant for a slingshot maneuver instead.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you discard the `science-based` tag, ignore how large space is, how large gas giants are, and have "spaceflight" happening at speeds that seem to be a few hundred miles per hour. That's how space combat works in *Star Wars*, which seems to work a lot like WWII dogfighting.

Under assumptions like that, diving into a gas giant is rather like going into a cloud in WWI or WWII aerial combat: it lets you hide, and if your opponent follows you, you can have a tightly-turning fight justified by atmospheric control surfaces.

Depending on how the engines of your space fighters are claimed to work, you may well be able to claim you can use the atmosphere for propulsion. Nuclear-heated ramjets might well be more plausible than the rest of the scenario.

Taking this route means you aren't dealing with science fiction any more: you're doing fantasy with SF trappings, and could perfectly well swap out your spacecraft for winged horses. If that's satisfactory for your aims, go ahead.